# Directory locations for ecryptfs

Tags: linux-mint, ecryptfs

I have a private ecryptfs directory mount set up on Linux Mint, and I was wondering about how exactly the relevant files are distributed on my computer.

Right now there's an `.ecryptfs`directory in `/home`, with a directory for my user which contains another `.ecryptfs` and `.Private`.  In my own home directory, there are `.ecryptfs` and `.Private` symlinks to those directories.
The way I understand it, `.ecryptfs` contains all the keys/mounting info, and `.Private` contains all the actual encrypted stuff.

My questions are: 
Is there any reason to have `.ecryptfs` and `.Private` symlinked to the actual directories in `/home/.ecrypfts`?
Can I just move them into my own home dir and remove `/home/.ecryptfs`?

Answer (score 1):

There's a very important reason that the real files/directories are in `/home/.ecryptfs/*` and the ones in `$HOME` are symlinks...

If you're using home directory encryption, `$HOME` is just a virtual presentation of your data in clear text.  The *real* data is actually in `/home/.ecryptfs/`.

The *real* data exists in `/home/.ecryptfs/` so that it can be mounted by the OS (pam_motd, actualy), and so that you can back it up.